# Max gap between two flex items in TailwindCSS

Tags: tailwind-css

How can I add the maximum possible gap between 2 items in TailwindCSS? I can add `gap-10` to add some gap but I can not find a way to have Text1 and Text2 as far away from each other as possible.

```html
<footer class="flex gap-10">
  <div class="">Text1</div>
  <div class="">Text2</div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [justify-between](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/justify-content#space-between) to add an equal amount of space between each item, when you have two items the space between them will grow to a maximum

```
<footer class="flex justify-between">
  <div>Text1</div>
  <div>Text2</div>
</footer>
```